# What do you call someone who is being lied to?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Someone who lies is called a liar but someone who is being lied to is called what? A victim?

Comment: Should the term apply to all "victims" (credulous and suspicious) ?

Comment: Welcome to our site! I see that you are a new contributor. Please edit your question to include two things. First, please include a couple possible sentences illustrating how you would use this term, leaving a blank `________` where it would go. Second, please **present your research** into this by showing us which possible terms you discovered but discarded, and tell us why you found each of those inappropriate for your purposes.

Comment: It's probably better to think in terms of your sought term meaning ***person who believes the liar***, rather than ***person being lied to***. There may be other terms besides ***dupe*** for the former definition, but I don't think English is likely to have a word to refer to everyone exposed to the lie (even if perhaps almost none of them actually *believe* it).

Comment: Why, _lieee_, of course. Just like _payee_, _legatee_, _contactee_, _callee_, _sayee_; thanks to _-ee_ suffix.

Answer (score 1):

The victim is perhaps a **dupe** (see [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dupe)) although it includes other forms of deception besides verbal lying.

For the verb form [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dupe) has

> If a person dupes you, they trick you into doing something or into believing something which is not true.

Deception usually involves lying in some shape of form.

Comment: Plenty more [where that came from](https://www.oed.com/view/th/class/126685).

Comment: As with _patsy_, _schmuck_, _mark_, words used by con-artists to refer to their victims usually with negative connotations, possibly not what the OP is asking?

Comment: @tchrist sure there are a lot of *dupes*.